# CS1061 'collectioncollectionbuilder<products, orderproducts>' does not contain a definition for 'hasforeignkey' and no accessible extension

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

cs1061 'collectioncollectionbuilder<products, orderproducts>' does not contain a definition for 'hasforeignkey' and no accessible extension method 'hasforeignkey' accepting a first argument of type 'collectioncollectionbuilder<products, orderproducts>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) cafeapiproject

```
using CafeApiProject.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CafeApiProject
{
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        DbSet<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
        DbSet<Products> Products { get; set; }
        DbSet<OrderProducts> OrderProducts { get; set; }
        DbSet<Employees> Employees { get; set; }
        DbSet<Orders> Orders { get; set; }
        DbSet<Customers> customers { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=CafeDb;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Products>()
               .HasOne(p => p.Category)
               .WithMany(c => c.Products)
               .HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoryId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<OrderProducts>()
                .HasMany(op => op.Product)
                .WithMany(c => c.Orders)
                .HasForeignKey(op => new { op.OrderId, op.ProductId });
            modelBuilder.Entity<Orders>()
                .HasOne(e => e.Employee)
                .WithMany(c => c.Orders)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.EmployeeId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Orders>()
                .HasOne(c => c.Customer)
                .WithMany(c => c.Orders)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.CustomerId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Orders>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Order)
                .WithMany(c => c.Orders)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.OrderId );






        }
    }
}


namespace CafeApiProject.Models
{
    public class Orders
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid OrderId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("OrderId")]
        public OrderProducts Order { get; set; }
        public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("Id")]
        public Customers Customer { get; set; }
        
        public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("EmployeeId")]
        public Employees Employee { get; set; }
        public string OrderList { get; set; }

    }
}
namespace CafeApiProject.Models
{ [PrimaryKey(nameof(OrderId), nameof(ProductId))]
    public class OrderProducts
    {
       
        public Guid OrderId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
        public ICollection<Products> Product { get; set; }   
        public ICollection<Orders> Orders { get; set; }
    }
}


namespace CafeApiProject.Models
{
    public class Products
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Article { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
        public ProductCategory Category { get; set; }
        public ICollection<OrderProducts> Orders { get; set; }
    }
        
}
```

plz help
also have error while trying to add migration:
"The entity type 'OrderProducts' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943."](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.%22)

Comment: What does this have to do with C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your entity classes and Fluent API, I see quite some issues to generate the `OrderProducts` entity which is the associate table for a many-to-many relationship between the `Order` and `Product` entities.

Orders:

1. An `Orders` entity should have one-to-many `OrderProducts`.
2. It seems like a conflict in which you declare the `CustomerId` column but you apply the `ForeignKey` attribute with `Id` for the related `Customer` property.

OrderProducts:

1. [EF Core doesn't support using the `Key` attribute for composite keys](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/key-attribute#composite-keys). Instead, you should do it in Fluent API with the [`HasKey` method](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/haskey-method#composite-keys).
2. The `OrderProducts` should refer to single `Orders` and `Products` entities respectively, but not multiple.

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Products>()
        .HasOne(p => p.Category)
        .WithMany(c => c.Products)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoryId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Orders>()
        .HasOne(e => e.Employee)
        .WithMany(c => c.Orders)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.EmployeeId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Orders>()
        .HasOne(c => c.Customer)
        .WithMany(c => c.Orders)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.CustomerId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<OrderProducts>()
        .HasKey(op => new { op.OrderId, op.ProductId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<OrderProducts>()
        .HasOne(op => op.Product)
        .WithMany(p => p.Orders)
        .HasForeignKey(op => op.OrderId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<OrderProducts>()
        .HasOne(op => op.Order)
        .WithMany(o => p.OrderProducts)
        .HasForeignKey(op => op.OrderId);
}
```

```cs
public class Orders
{
    [Key]
    public Guid OrderId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OrderProducts> OrderProducts { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]  // Id for storing CustomerId, really?
    public Customers Customer { get; set; }
        
    [Required]
    public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EmployeeId")]
    public Employees Employee { get; set; }
    public string OrderList { get; set; }
}

public class OrderProducts
{
    [Required]
    public Guid OrderId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }

    public Products Product { get; set; }  
 
    public Orders Order { get; set; }
}

public class Products
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Article { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public ProductCategory Category { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OrderProducts> Orders { get; set; }
}
```